# How to use NAT iptables rules for hostapd

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, hostapd

My PC is equipped with two net interfaces, `wlan0` & `eth0`, and I want to use WiFi port as an access point on `wlan0`.

- I used `hostapd` facility and it works properly in routing mode within the local network; users can connect to the access point and DHCP works properly in both segments.
- The PC with `hostapd` does not have any firewalls or `iptables` rules (`iptables` and firewalls disabled), as I want to only use the built-in firewall of the ADSL router.

My net config is as follows:

- `PC with hostapd  ->  cable connection  ->  ADSL router`
- `wlan0  ->  eth0  <->  192.168.0.1  <->  internet`
- `192.168.10.1  ->  192.168.0.7  ->  static routing to 192.168.10.X`

PC `ifconfig`:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:12:3F:F2:31:65
      inet addr:192.168.0.7  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::212:3fff:fef2:3165/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2169539 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1008097 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:3056198487 (2.8 GiB)  TX bytes:72727161 (69.3 MiB)
      Interrupt:16

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:3398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:495444 (483.8 KiB)  TX bytes:495444 (483.8 KiB)

mon.wlan0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-14-A5-04-94-3C-90-F0-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:17092 (16.6 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:14:A5:04:94:3C
      inet addr:192.168.10.1  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::214:a5ff:fe04:943c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1502 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:279392 (272.8 KiB)
```

How do I configure a simple NAT `iptables` config to it on the PC?

- I want all users connected to the network via `hostapd` (network `192.168.10.X`) to have access to and from internet
- I dont want to filter any traffic, just only NAT.

---

I cannot get a connection to the internet from the WiFi segment:

- The client connected to WiFi has DHCP address `192.168.10.48`, and the only traffic is on `eth0` from address:

  ```
  16:50:14.671587 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.48 tell 192.168.0.1, length 46
  ```

  Note: The address is `192.168.0.48` not `192.168.10.48`, so Masquerade seams to work.
- I can no longer ping `192.168.0.1` [ADSL router], which was possible before.
- What about access from the internet to the WIFI Users? Of course I will setup in ADSL router, forwarding particular IP port pooling from Internet to particular IP address of such WiFi user.

---

**EDIT 1:**

- `systemctl` shows `iptables` as:

  ```
  iptables.service          loaded active exited
  ```

  Even though I ran:

  ```
  systemctl enable iptables.service
  systemctl start iptables.service
  ```

**EDIT 2:**

- It works, but each time I boot the computer, is it normal to have to manually add the following via a startup script?

  ```bsh
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
  ```

Comment: See my updated response below...

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a firewall for all occasions.
Please read the README and the SCRIPT before using it.
I included the necessary rules for HOSTAP

> Essential Parts:

## HostAP

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

## HostAP requires the lines below to both be ACCEPT to function

```
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT >> /dev/null 2>&1 
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

https://github.com/diveyez/fw.sh

Comment: Note that `iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT` allows all incoming traffic to your Linux machine. Not the safest option.

Answer (score 7):

In the simplest form:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

That will allow all WiFi users access *to* the Internet.

Of course assuming your other routing setup is already done, namely:

1. Forwarding enabled in the kernel

   ```
   sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   ```
2. Forwarding enabled in `iptables`:

   ```
   iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
   iptables -F FORWARD
   ```

Use `tcpdump -nn -i eth0` to watch the traffic on `eth0` in case of problems to see if it gets NATed properly, if the response is coming back, etc.

**EDIT:** *"I have to add manually each time i boot computer (from startup script)..."*
It depends on what Linux distribution you have. Sadly pretty much each distro has its own Firewall tool - in the end they're only calling `iptables` but for some reason the authors believe that obfuscating the way iptables work is what the users want.

To answer your question - the most likely your firewall can be configured to add this NAT rule automatically. The exact way however varies between Linux distros for no good reason. Sad but true.

Comment: All firewalls on PC are disabled. The only running service is iptables

Comment: iptables == firewall -- Somehow you need to configure iptables to emit that MASQUERADE rule. How? It depends on your linux distribution. There must be config file somewhere. Where? It depends on your linux distribution.

Comment: So You have mu iptables ruled:

Comment: So You have mu iptables ruled: [root@media ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination.    And I and such line in startup : iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE. So my implementation of iptables is de facto "transparent" firewall - or no-firewall